# Manual focus stacking Camera2 Api

Tags: android, camera, focus

I am trying to implement an android app with the `Camera2` api, which should take pictures with various focus distances, something like focus stacking.

I have trouble with the manual focus, how do I trigger the focus action?
The `LENS_STATUS` is always static, so my images are always unfocused - no focusing has been done.
I have set the `AF_MODE` to `OFF` and setting the focus distance with:

```
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, minFocus);
```

Can anyone give a hint on how to trigger camera to focus?

Comment: Your question and goal are at odds. If you want to manually focus by turning AF off and manually setting the lens focus distance, by definition you cannot trigger it to focus. Are you sure your device allows manual focus in the first place, and does it have calibrated focus units?

Comment: Yes, I bought Nexus 6 just for this purpose. How do I force it to focus on the defined manual distance?

Comment: Without more information (code) I cannot tell, but you appear to be setting the relevant flags and values in your `CaptureRequest`. The `LENS_STATE` _should_ be `STATIONARY`, and there is no focus for you to trigger because you turned it off. _If_ the Nexus 6 has `android.lens.info.focusDistanceCalibration = "CALIBRATED"` then your focus point should be the inverse of whatever float value to set for it. Is this not the case, if all these things are true?

Comment: I just checked the calibration and it is indeed `android.lens.info.focusDistanceCalibration = "CALIBRATED"` and the . `LENS_STATE = "STATIONARY"`. But never the less, any distance that I set is ignored, the saved images are always blurry. 

One thing that I observed is that the lens is not moving while taking a picture, so this is what I meant by "triggering" the focus, how do I get the maual focus distance to kick in?

Comment: The lens will not (and should not) move if you have manually set the focus and turned off AF, I'm not sure why you're expecting or wanting it to. You're using appropriate diopter units for your `minFocus` value, instead of an actual distance, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using diopter units. Maybe I am using the wrong term when I say "moving". I want to take a burst of pictures, where each of them has a different focus. But all of them look the same - blurry and unfocused, so the manual focus I set does not do anything. I thought that some kind of trigger would be needed to force the camera to refocus with the given parameter.

Comment: Got it. Sorry for the confusion. It is very strange the lens is not honoring your request. Are you using a burst capture command to the `CameraCaptureSession`, or a sequence of the `.capture(...)` methods? I also have a rack-focus script which works on my Nexus 5, and a successful for me `CaptureRequest` has relevant field values:     `"android.control.afMode": "OFF",
    "android.control.afTrigger": "IDLE",
    "android.control.captureIntent": "STILL_CAPTURE",
    "android.control.mode": "AUTO",
    "android.lens.focusDistance": "14.0"`